# Managing photos that belong to different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app that allows users to post articles with photos. Articles have many photos and each photo belongs to only one article.

The photos from the articles reside in the Photos table. These photos are uploaded via carrierwave + fog to S3.

In order to make this feature work, I have a series of files named around it. For example, Photos controller, Photos model, Photos view, and Photos.coffee to display previews.

Now I want to add a feature that allows users to upload an avatar. Should I store both the avatar and articles' photos in one database table
(Photos) or use another table for the avatars?

If I use the same table, the rows will have a null value. For example, article_id will be filled in while user_id will be blank for photos that belong to articles. For avatars, the article_id will be blank and user_id will have the corresponding user's id.

If I use a different table, I think I have to rewrite the Photos controller, Photos model and Photos view because now the table is for Avatars. Is there a better way to do this than to rewrite the article photos uploader for user avatars?

Let me know how you think I should approach this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If user will have only one avatar, i will add avatar to user table, but if you would like to save more than one (avatars history for example), better have it in another table. You can always use [polymorphic-associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) for that, to fix issue with `article_id` and `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

If the avatar are related to the article, then I would put it on the article table. If the avatar is related to the user, I would do as @Argonus mentioned. I would not put the avatar in the photos table. It wouldn't make sense.

I assume your photo controller, view, and model handle only image/photo specific functionality. Since the avatar is an image, you could still use the photo controller and view, and have different models for different image types. In this case you would have two models, the photos model and the avatar model.

Finally, switch between models given the context of the view.

Comment: Yes, but you can also use inheritance for that. For example Assets table and Image < Asset && Avatar < Asset.